# Excel Vba: Run macro on ANY key stroke / press

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following vba code to run a macro on the enter key press event. However is there a way i can alter this code to run on any keystroke not just enter?

here is the code i am using:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If KeyAscii = 13 Then
MsgBox "You Pressed a key"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since `KeyAscii` will always be [positive](http://thecodeforyou.blogspot.nl/2013/01/vb-keyascii-values.html), try:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii > -1 Then
        MsgBox "You Pressed a key"
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, I've checked it just now, you must remove the `As MSForms.Returninteger` part. The code I have just posted works perfectly fine for me.